# VBA Find function incorrect highlighting

Tags: vba

Can somebody help me fix this code, I have two textbox where when you paste the text on the 1st Textbox and click the search button, it highlighted the exact text on the 2nd textbox if it is present on the 2nd textbox. But when the string on 2nd textbox contains linefeed/newline, it added one character from the start of the text. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub FindText(ByVal start_at As Integer)
Dim pos As Integer
Dim target As String

    target = Textbox1.Text
    pos = InStr(start_at, Textbox2.Text, target)
    If pos > 0 Then
        ' We found it.
        TargetPosition = pos
        Textbox2.SelStart = TargetPosition - 1
        Textbox2.SelLength = Len(target)
        Textbox2.SetFocus
    Else
        ' We did not find it.
        MsgBox "Not found."
        Textbox2.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

' Search button
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    FindText 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your problem? What is the output your are expectin and what are you getting instead

Comment: if the string in Textbox2 contains new line (Enter Character it added additional character when text are highlighted

Comment: Can you provide edit the code for me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that Textbox is treating newline as a single character while `Len()` counts as `CRLF` as two. You should probably count the number of times `CRLF` appears in the text preceding the match `target` and adjust `SelStart` accordingly. Try this line instead:

```
Textbox2.SelStart = Len(Replace(Left(target, pos - 1), vbCrLf, "^")) - 1
'Textbox2.SelLength = Len(Replace(target, vbCrLf, "^"))
```

If `target` can include line breaks you may have a similar problem with `SelLength` which is why I've left the second, commented line. This works by substituting two-character line-break sequences into a single-character string. It's completely arbitrary what value to use for replacement since the result is discarded and only the length ultimately matters.

Comment: No, `x` should have been the variable `target`.

Comment: it didn't solve the issue. it is the CRLF in Textbox2 is the problem, I think the replacement happens on Texbox1

Comment: @audiophilia You misunderstand what's supposed to be happening. And I know you can't post a screenshot with your low rep but you can still do a better job describing what you're actually seeing.

Comment: the highlighting is the problem in textbox2, after the CRLF the highlighted text is adding additional character, Let say the text is Textboxt2 is like the text below:
"Joel and Ted
are my bestfriend"

and Textbox1 = "my"
the text highlighted was y_ (y and space). It is moving one character to the left every CRLF in String.

Comment: So it sounds like you need to look at the text prior to the match. It's not adding additional characters, it's just that the offset is wrong. Your original description of the problem is not accurate.